# Visual Studio Windows Emulator cannot run. give "The interface is unknown" error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

Can any Windows Phone Application developer help?

When i run my project, emulator starts and shut down, and the error `The interface is unknown` is displayed in error log in Visual Studio.

It was running fine the other day.

What should i do to get rid of this error?

Comment: If it was working the other day and doesn't work today, what's different? What have you done in the meantime? Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: No i haven't done done anything in the meantime

Comment: Is this error specific to one project or is it affecting all your projects? (you could test with a new project).

Comment: it's working fine today, don't know what the problem was :(

Comment: Identified what the problem was :-)
"Windows Phone Emulator-512" is compatible with only Visual Studio 2012; it is not backward compatible with earlier versions of Visual Studio. So, now i used "Windows Phone Emulator-256", it's working fine :-)
Thanks to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Maybe this can help solve your issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492200/vs-express-2012-windows-phone-8-sdk-the-interface-is-unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified what the problem was :-)
"Windows Phone Emulator-512" is compatible with only Visual Studio 2012; it is not backward compatible with earlier versions of Visual Studio. So, now i used "Windows Phone Emulator-256", it's working fine :-)
Thanks to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, the window phone emulator for widow phone 7 series suites your PC. if you are experiencing problems with it, simply download Visual studio 2010 service pack 1 and re-install the tools. you can also update your .net frameworks from windows update.
if you are using Visual studio 2012, then you must be using the window phone 8 emulator which runs on only 64 bit and window 8 pro (or advanced) machines. it works on the visual machine. so you can re-install your Hyper V drivers or re-install the SDK
i hope this help fix the problem permanently.