# VS Express 2012, Windows Phone 8 SDK: The interface is unknown

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I can't deploy applications to to my Windows Phone 8 device from Visual Studio Express 2012 anymore. I always get the following two lines in the console:

```
Deployment of application to device failed.
The interface is unknown.
```

The emulator also does not work anymore (xde.exe just crashes). All that worked once (Hyper-V is active).

All that happened without a change to my app (the same happens with a fresh hello world app).
The problem is not my phone, I tested a different phone (even different model), same problem.

I already completely removed and reinstalled the Phone SDK including Visual Studio.

The problem might have occurred since I updated to Windows 8.1 but I am not sure about this.

If anybody has a clue of what is going on here I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Try running devenv.exe /SafeMode.

Comment: Was it working before?

Comment: @AlexandruLache where do I find devenv.exe?

Comment: @Creator yes it was working before, emulator and device debugging

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already tried removing/reinstalling VS and SDK, try creating a new user account on your Win8.1 box and running VS from that.  If it works, the problem was probably some settings in CurrentUser registry hive, which Remove doesn't always clean up.  Reinstall the already-installed VS and SDK may work better.

The 'interface' error means this is likely some COM issue, and that implicates registry.  If you can figure out which DLL contains the interface, you may be able to fix it with (admin command line) `> REGSVR32 <dllPath>`.  You can trace the registry accesses being made when you try to debug the app via SystemInternals [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Comment: de nada.  but if you were able to fix this, what worked for you?